# iPad using Shell does not fill portrait, but scales to landscape

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, ipad, xamarin.forms.shell

I am currently developing from Visual Studios, we have been working on iPhone primarily, but a scope has crept in to support iPad.

We are using Xamarin.Forms.Shell for our main page and navigation, but all the content pages are not filling the iPad. The navigation buttons are at the bottom as expected, but the content within while in portrait stops half way.

in info.plist I have Device Orientation checked all boxes, devices set tot Universal.

This happens on all pages.

What could I be missing?

[image: Visual representation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `VerticalOptions` could be not set to `expand`, e.g: `StartAndExpand` or `FillAndExpand`.

Also, your `stackLayout HeightRequest` could be setted. If so, then the height will be limited as is.

Check also the main orientation of your project, if is Portrait or Landscape.

If the steps above don't work, please, edit your question and put the XAML of this page.

Comment: Thanks, I will review the expand settings on vertical options and share a normalised content view.

Comment: Anything to update?

Comment: Sorry been swamped with different tasks in iPhone, looks promising. I marked each item that had a VerticalOption to include exanpand and it worked on that one page. I'll put it through the rest and see